# position a component relative to its parent in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to position my child component relative to my parent component but the problem is that in the first render it places the child out of the scop until a setState happens. after any setState, it will work properly.
can you help me out with positioning it properly?
here's how I call my component:

`<CardC title={"anything"} x={10} y={10}  field1={"something else"} minh={130} minw={250} height={150} width={250}/>`

and this is the child component itself

```
class CardC extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
        width: props.width,
        height:props.height,
        x:props.x,
        y:props.y

    }
}

render() {
    return <div className='card'>
        <div>
            <Rnd

                size={{width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height}}

                position={{x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y}}
                onDragStop={(e, d) => {
                    this.setState({x: d.x, y: d.y})
                }}
                onResize={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
                    this.setState({
                        width: ref.style.width,
                        height: ref.style.height,
                        ...position,
                    });
                }}
                minWidth={this.props.minw}
                minHeight={this.props.minh}
                bounds=".content"
            >
                <Card title={this.props.title} extra={<a href="#">More</a>} style={{height: '100%'}}>

                    <p>{this.props.field1}</p>
                    <p>{this.state.height}</p>
                    <p>Card content</p> 
                </Card>
            </Rnd>

        </div>

    </div>;
}
```

}

Comment: have you try to run setState in [componentdidupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)?

Comment: I will try that